# Does t.length >>> 0 anything in the MDN JS Array polyfil?

Tags: javascript

In the MDN Array PolyFils, it has the following line.

```
var len = t.length >>> 0;
```

Does binary shift right 0 really actualy do anything, or can I take this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it does something. Whatever the value may be, it'll convert it to an unsigned 32-bit number.

If a numeric conversion wasn't possible, you'll get `0`. This handles odd cases where `.length` is some unexpected value.

This is basically how they implement instructions in the spec. Like in the [specification for `.forEach()`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.18):

> 1. ...
> 2. Let `lenValue` be the result of calling the `[[Get]]` internal method of `O` with the argument `"length"`.
> 3. Let `len` be `ToUint32(lenValue)`.

Answer (score 1):

`>>>` is the **[unsigned right shift operator](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.7.3)**. The unsigned right shift operator is used in array method, to ensure that the length property is a unsigned 32-bit integer.

According to the [specs](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.4):

> Every Array object has a length property whose value is always a
>   nonnegative integer less than 2<sup>32</sup>.